# Movie clip equivalent in Google Web Designer

Tags: css, adobe-animate, google-web-designer

Simple question:
Does google web designer have something similar to a movie clip in Flash / Adobe animate cc? If not: why is that?

info:
A movieclip is like an animated element of which the timeline runs completely independent of the main timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out GWD has something similar. It's called a group. I completely missed this because I thought it was just an SVG group.